# PHP MySql error Can't read id from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following login/register tutorial in php and mysql. As you can see in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUk2e8oqOvI&list=PLE134D877783367C7

You can find function user_id_from_username on 06:28 minute.

I have exact function:

```
function user_id_from_username($username){                  
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
```

But this query never returns user_id. I tried to echo result of this query and I don't get anything. Database is ok, all other queries works fine. If I run this query in mysql workbench again it works. I don't know where is the problem. Can you help me.

Comment: If your tutorial teaches you to use `mysql_*` function, that may be a hint that the tutorial is a little bit outdated; Use [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), especially [prepared statement and variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: remove single qoutes in user_id, users and username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes around user_id, users and username.

Quotes are only for string

```
mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")
```

or optimized

```
mysql_query('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = "' . $username . '";')
```

Comment: All of those answers worked but I choose this one, because it's simplest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use " insteand of '

```
"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'"
```

Comment: if you use ', all string in ' will be handled as pure string,include $

Comment: Nightmare why didn't you edit your post?

Answer (score 0):

```
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '".$username."'"), 0, 'user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the data from mysql_result.

```
function user_id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '".$username."'"), 0, 'user_id');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['user_id'];    
}
```

Comment: How sure are you that this works? :)

Comment: you have to fetch the query resultset if you want to obtain data from a query result. But that 'result' is missing a $ sign.

Comment: It is indeed, Fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 'username' = '".$username."'"   replace this in query and try again
```